# Why does an image fit on my personal comptuer but on a different computer it isn't the same dimensions? HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I have to make a website for my html class.
When I open the page on my computer, the images fit how I want them to fit. 
But when I try to open it on the school computers, it is like 50% of what I expect it to be. I'm guessing its because of different screen resolutions. How do I make it work on all resolutions? 
Here's a picture. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaCEX.png

The logo on the top stays in position but the pink bar wont. It doesnt fill across the entire screen.
My html is `<div id="headbar">
        <img src="headbar.png" alt="bar" />
    </div>`

My css is

```
#headbar {
position: fixed;
margin-top: 85px;
width: 100%;
z-index: -1;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is headbar.png a image that should make `#headbar` fully pink? Then it could be as simple as :

```
#headbar img {width: 100%}
```

It will then be scaled though. To prevent this, give `#headbar` a height and make the image 100% height. Of course it would make more sense to make it a background image (or color if it is pink only).

Edit - going on current information, would this be what you're after?

```
#headbar {
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
position: fixed;
margin-top: 85px;
z-index: -1;
background-image: url(headbar.png);
background-size: 100% 100%
}
```

I've just added some height - adapt this to what fits best. One more thing to beware of is to get the correct path to the image (absolute url is easiest)

```
background-image: url(/imagefolder/headbar.png);
```

Comment: I made a pink square bar using MS Paint and then I put the image inside the div and postiioned it with css

Comment: Please show all relevant CSS then and elaborate on the exact intention. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. 
The css is    
  
`#headbar {
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 85px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    background-attachment: fixed;` 

The intention is to have it fit across the whole screen horizontally at any screen resolution.

Comment: Updated the answers. From what I understand, using the image as a background would be appropriate. Let me know if it is not what you had in mind after all.

Comment: Thats what I needed. I didnt think it would make a difference if I made it as a background image. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. I'll even out your downvote by the way - everybody's gotta learn stuff sometimes.But it always helps to be as specific as you can here on SO.

Comment: Making it a background is just semantically more correct, the trick is in the `background-size` property which makes it adapt to the element's dimensions. Leave that out and it will look as before...

Answer (score 1):

Use Media Queries in CSS.

Example:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1400px) { 

#headbar {
position: fixed;
margin-top: 85px;
width: 100%;
z-index: -1;
background-attachment: fixed;

}

@media (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 1200px) { 

#headbar {
position: fixed;
margin-top: 35px;
width: 100%;
z-index: -1;
background-attachment: fixed;

}
```

Comment: I tried that and it messes up the flow of the whole website.
http://i.imgur.com/S9X7egj.png

Comment: edit the parameters you need according to the size of the screen you want to view.

Comment: edit here: (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1400px)
edit here too: margin-top: 85px;

and in other locale u need...